# How to parse Json formatted Kafka message in spark streaming

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have JSON messages on Kafka like this:

> `{"id_post":"p1", "message":"blablabla"}`

and I want to parse the message, and print (or use for further computation) the `message` element.
With the following code I print the json

```
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, inputGroup, topicMap)
val postStream = kafkaStream.map(_._2)
postStream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
val count = rdd.count()
if (count > 0){
    rdd.foreach(record => {
      println(record)
    }
}
```

but I can't manage to get the single element. 
I tried a few JSON parser, but no luck. 
Any idea?

> update:
>   a few errors with different JSON parser
>   this is the code and output with [circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe) parser:

```
val parsed_record = parse(record)
```

and the output:

```
14:45:00,676 ERROR Executor:95 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at io.circe.jawn.CirceSupportParser$$anon$1$$anon$4.add(CirceSupportParser.scala:36)
        at jawn.CharBasedParser$class.parseString(CharBasedParser.scala:90)
        at jawn.StringParser.parseString(StringParser.scala:15)
        at jawn.Parser.rparse(Parser.scala:397)
        at jawn.Parser.parse(Parser.scala:338)
        at jawn.SyncParser.parse(SyncParser.scala:24)
        at jawn.SupportParser$$anonfun$parseFromString$1.apply(SupportParser.scala:15)
```

and so on.. at the row in which I use `parse(record)` 
looks like it can't access and/or parse the string `record`.

Same if I use [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) 
at the `parse(record)` the error output is more or less the same:

```
16:58:20,425 ERROR Executor:95 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.runtime.ObjectRef.create(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/runtime/ObjectRef;
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$$anonfun$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:144)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$$anonfun$2.apply(JsonParser.scala:141)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$.parse(JsonParser.scala:80)
at net.liftweb.json.JsonParser$.parse(JsonParser.scala:45)
at net.liftweb.json.package$.parse(package.scala:40)
at SparkConsumer$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SparkConsumer.scala:98)
at SparkConsumer$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SparkConsumer.scala:95)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
```

at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)

Comment: Which problem did you experienced with the JSON parser?

Comment: What if the JSON has multiple linefeed characters `\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue, so I am writing here for future references:

**dependencies, dependencies, dependecies!**

I choose to use [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json), but this applies to any JSON parser and/or framework.

The SPARK version I am using (*v1.4.1*) is the one compatible with scala 2.10, here the dependencies from pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and some other libraries. I was using the lift-json version for scala 2.11 ... and that is **WRONG**.

So, for the future me and if you are reading this topic: be coherent with scala version and among dependencies. 
In lift-json case:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
            <artifactId>lift-json_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem with you.

However I solved this problem by using the `fastjson`.

`SBT dependency :
    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson
    libraryDependencies += "com.alibaba" % "fastjson" % "1.2.12"`

or

`Maven dependency : 
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>`

You can have a try. Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the Data from JSON String in Scala/Apache Spark

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object JsonData extends serializable{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val msg = "{ \"id_post\":\"21\",\"message\":\"blablabla\"}";
    val m1 = msgParse(msg)
    println(m1.id_post)
  }
  case class SomeClass(id_post: String, message: String) extends serializable
  def msgParse(msg: String): SomeClass = {
    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val m = parse(msg).extract[SomeClass]
      return m

  }

}
```

Below is the Maven Decency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>json4s-native_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```